# Mysterious batch file

Tags: cmd, helper

While searching through my file directories, I came across a batch file that I had not created. While running the program, (after safety removing all external devices and logging out of all possible accounts) A CMD box would open for a brief second and then close. Upon editing the code so the CMD box would pause,  I discovered what its doing.

[image]

Below is the original text from the batch file:

```
PUSHD .
cd %windir%\system32
@setlocal
@set logfile="%temp%\bcm_vc80redist.log"

@echo [%date% %time%] START vcredist_x86.exe /q:a /r:i /c:"msiexec /i vcredist.msi /qn" >> %logfile%
vcredist_x86.exe /q:a /r:i /c:"msiexec /i vcredist.msi /qn"

@if errorlevel 0 echo vcredist_x86.exe exited with errorlevel=%errorlevel% >> %logfile%
@echo [%date% %time%] END vcredist_x86.exe /q:a /r:i /c:"msiexec /i vcredist.msi /qn" >> %logfile%

@endlocal
POPD

{Pause}--This isnt part of the original code, this is added to stop the CMD box from closing.
```

---

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Did you actually try searching for `vcredist_x86.exe` by any chance? Talk about paranoia.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that some point you installed a "Visual C++ Redistributable Package" and the batch file is a leftover from the installation.

You can look in `%temp%\bcm_vc80redist.log` to see exactly what was installed.

---

Source [Developer Tools
Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

> The Visual C++ Redistributable Packages install run-time components
>   that are required to run C++ applications that are built by using
>   Visual Studio 2013.
>
> [image]
>
> The Visual C++ Redistributable Packages install run-time components
>   that are required to run applications that are developed by using
>   Visual Studio 2013, on computers that don't have Visual Studio 2013
>   installed. These packages install run-time components of these
>   libraries: C Runtime (CRT), Standard C++, ATL, MFC, C++ AMP, and
>   OpenMP.